# How to set data to QComboBox using QAbstractTableModel (Model/View)?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5, pyside2

I wish to be able to set the `itemData` of a `combobox` when populated using a `QAbstractTableModel`. However, I can only return one string from the model's `data` method.

Usually, when not using a model, this can be performed like so:

```
# Set text and data
combobox.addItem('Some text', 'some item data')

# Retrieve data from selected
item_data = combobox.itemData(combobox.currentIndex())
```

**How can this be done, but using `QAbstractTableModel`?**

---

I have a `combobox`, which I set a model to:

```
model = ProjectTableModel(projects)
combobox.setModel(model)
```

My model:

```
class ProjectTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, projects=[], parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._projects = projects

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._projects)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and column == 0:
            project = self._projects[row]
            name = project.name()
            id = project.id()  # <----- how to add this as itemData?
            return name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QComboBox` *always* uses a model to store its data. If you don't set a model yourself, it will create its own `QStandardItemModel`. Methods such as `addItem` and `itemData` simply store and retrieve values using whatever underlying model has been set. By default, the combo-box uses the `Qt.UserRole` to store item-data in the model. So your model just needs to do something like this:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()

    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and column == 0:
        project = self._projects[row]
        name = project.name()
        return name
    elif role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole and column == 0:
        project = self._projects[row]
        id = project.id()
        return id

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()

    if role == QtCore.Qt.UserData and column == 0:
        project = self._projects[row]
        project.setId(value) # or whatever
```